# Multi client connect through same IP to server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, tcp

I have this scenario in mind, can I connect group of clients that have the same IP -Located on the same computer- to server which recognize them by their username and password and not by their IPs .. I want to know if this possible.

I'm using [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/TCPIPChat.aspx) template of TCP/IP application.

Comment: I've added the C# tag to get more views.

Answer (score 0):

You can start (almost) any number of clients on one machine that connect to the same server. The only restriction is the number of ports you have available. A client socket is identified by an ipaddress:port pair, so if you start each client on a different port, it will work.

Comment: What about using username/password instead of port?

Comment: Username/password are on the application layer (7), while ipaddress/port are on the ip layer (3). Before your username/password can come into play, the system will not let you open more than one socket on the same port. You can implement what you want, but anyway the port contraint must be fulfilled, which is itself sufficient to differentiate between clients.